# Using datepicker plugin in Onsen UI 2

Tags: onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

In my app, I want to use native datepicker and tried to use [this](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker) plugin, but failed to make it work. I just recently started working with Onsen UI 2 and haven't experience with using the plugins, so I might be missing something.

I followed the steps of installing and usage of the plugin. My code so far.

### index.html:

```
<ons-list-item ng-click="ctrl.showPicker();">
    Set the time
</ons-list-item>
```

where 'ctrl' is my controller.

### index.js

```
this.showPicker = function() {
    var options = {
        date: new Date(),
        mode: 'date'
    };

    function onSuccess(date) {
        alert('Selected date: ' + date);
    }

    function onError(error) { // Android only
        alert('Error: ' + error);
    }

    var datePicker = new DatePicker();
    datePicker.show(options, onSuccess, onError);
}
```

Unfortunetely, clicking the list item shows me this error:

```
ReferenceError: DatePicker is not defined
```

As I said, I don't have experience using the plugins in Onsen UI 2, so far I was using Cordova framework (javascript and jquery). Can anyone tell me, what can I do to make the plugin work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your angular code looks ok. The only problem is that you don't have a `DatePicker` variable.

Looking at docs of the plugin which you're using it seems that it doesn't export a `DatePicker` function.

In the docs they are using just `datePicker.show`, so maybe they are just exporting `datePicker`.

So basically all you need to do is remove the following line:

```
var datePicker = new DatePicker();
```

And you should be fine (if you installed your plugin correctly).